# Delayed Monarch flight

Tags: air-travel, delays, charter

What time did Monarch flight ZB7014 from Gatwick land in Rhodes on 2nd September 2015. It was due at 12 noon and we calculated our arrival as 3hrs 15 minutes late. Monarch airlines say it was only 2 hrs 45 minutes. The original plane had a technical problem and was withdrawn, the replacement aircraft from Prestige, a Spanish company blew a tyre on arrival which had to be replaced before we could finally take off.

Comment: Be aware that airlines often use the touchdown time as 'arrival', not when the door is open at the gate.

Comment: And I thought you were going to say the monarch migration was delayed!

Comment: @Aganju I am sure that many airlines continue the practise, but in the case of Germanwings v Henning, the Court of Justice of the European Union overturned that position for the purposes of EC 261/2004. The arrival time is when the first door on the aircraft is opened. [p 22-25, http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:62013CJ0452&from=EN]

Answer (score 2):

Check at flightaware (https://flightaware.com/live/flight/MON7014).

In the lower part, they show the last fourteen days; you can buy a membership to see all data back to 1998 or so.

If you are lucky, someone here reads that and has a membership and looks it up for you for free.